# How to catch hibernate's lazy loadings?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to optimize a page where a lot of objects are loaded many of which use hibernate's lazy loading for their properties. But it's hard to find all of them manually because when I see say `someItem.getSmth()` I don't know that it's actually lazy loaded (it's not my code) besides I can skip some of these loadings anyway hence I need some automatic way of finding it. I tried to turn on hibernate's SQL logging but it's impossible to read it because it writes about 50 megs of logs per page load and it doesn't tell me where the query was called from. Is it possible to know somehow which objects are lazy loaded and from where?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to know somehow which objects are lazy loaded and from where?

You could parse your entity beans for the annotations `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne` and `ManyToMany`, if found, check for the property `fetch` whether it has the value `FetchType.LAZY`.

This could allow you to know which objects a lazy loaded and from which classes but not methods where the call is.

Comment: But this is what I call "manually" :) I can miss a lot of things this way because there a lot of objects are loaded and a lot of scenarios of loading data, so it's really difficult to find everything manually.

Comment: @mykola, well you tried to dig into 50M large lags "maually" too! For such tasks, unless there is already a tool which helps on it, you will always have to "manually" write some small utility to automatically do it for you, one which parses the log files using some regular expressions extracting thins you want. If you don't need the methods where the lazy loading methods are called from, then the approach in the answer is OK and you will not miss anything. Also please add a description of the set of *things* you want to find out in your question, it'll help people give better suited answers.

Comment: the problem is that there's nothing to parse because hibernate log doesn't contain information on whether it was lazy loading or something else.

Comment: @mykola Well it seems that the only way you can do it is to analyze the code. If you want to do it in one step and not in runtime then above approach might be workable. If you want to do it in runtime, then you might want to look in to [aspectj](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and intercept method call to methods annotated with the above annotations, onece you have them you can proceed just like in approach above too.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll try to dig into it (aspectj)